# How to offset a button to it's original position?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a button in the top right corner of my app and I want to animate something with this button in the middle of the screen. Once the animation ends, I want the button to offset itself with an animation to its original position.

Is there something like `offset(to: positionOfButton)` ?

Right now my Top bar with the coin amount button is in a separate view.

```
VStack {
TopBar()
// Other button in the middle of screen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something like .offset(x:y:)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/offset(x:y:)

Comment: How would I get the x and y of the button when it is in another view?

Comment: Also if I use `.offset(x:y:)` it instantly offsets the button. But I want to wait until my animation is over

Comment: If you need to offset something OUTSIDE de bounds of the view you are in, something is wrong in your view hierarchy. But you could put a GeometryReader on your top view, and pass down the geometryProxy until your element that you want to offset. Off course you'll need to calculate the x and y offset wanted using this geometry.size.width and geometry.size.height

Answer (score 0):

```
 VStack {
    TopBar()
    Button()
    .offset(x: 20, y: 50)
    
    }
```

Comment: textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50)